# Git check-out from ant target or python

Tags: python, git, ant, build

During our build , we call ANT from our Python .For code checkout,We have two options to checkout code from Git.

1. Pull code directly from Python script
2. Make an ANT target to pull code , Call that target from Python.

Can anyone please brief about pros and cons of both approach. I am new to all three tech.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the end it is the git executable which will be called to actually do the checkout. So either python calls git, or python calls ant which calls git. Just take the simplest, python which calls git via [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

Answer (score 1):

I would make with ant - it standard tool for Java-platform. May be generate ant from python or other one. Lack of this manner is not flexible of ant by comparison with Python.

Lack of Python-based solution is greater complexity of deployment in future: for linux good practice make packet, for Windows you have install python and libs manually.